# Why does my program crashes when I tried adding a node inside a function but works in the main function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I tried allocating a new node for a linked list using:

```
struct node *n;
n=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

When I try to do this inside a function which I call `newnode()`, it crashes. However, when it works when it is done inside the `main()` function.My full code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node{
int item;
struct node *next;
};

struct linkedlist{
    int size;
    struct node *head;
};

void split(struct linkedlist *LL,struct linkedlist *L_odd,
struct linkedlist *L_even);

void printlist(struct linkedlist *LL);

void generate();

void newnode(int i,struct linkedlist *LL);

int main(){
    struct linkedlist *L=(struct linkedlist*)malloc(sizeof(struct linkedlist));
    L->head->item=1;
    newnode(2,L);
    newnode(3,L);
    printlist(L);
 return 0;
}

void split(struct linkedlist *LL,struct linkedlist *L_odd,
struct linkedlist *L_even){
    bool odd=1;
    bool start=1;
    struct node *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *tempo=L_odd->head;
    struct node *tempe=L_even->head;
    temp=LL->head;
    while (temp->next != NULL){
        if(odd==1){
            if (start == 1 ){
                start=0;
            }
            else{
            tempe->next=temp->next;
            tempe=tempo->next;
            }
            tempo->item=temp->item;
            odd=0;
        }
        else if(odd==0){
            tempo->next=temp->next;
            tempo=tempo->next;
            L_even->head->item=temp->item;
            odd=1;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void printlist(struct linkedlist *LL){
    struct node *temp=LL->head;
    do{
        printf("%d ",temp->item);
        temp=temp->next;
    }while(temp!= NULL);
}

void generate(){

}

void newnode(int i,struct linkedlist *LL){
    struct node *n;
    n=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //Program crashes here
        printf("%d",LL->head->item);
    //n->item=i;
    struct node *temp=LL->head;

    while (temp->next!=NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    //temp->next=n;
    //n->next=NULL;
}
```

Why is this so?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Hi I've tried removing the cast but it still crashes

Comment: Sourav was just trolling.

Comment: @PeterSchneider I'm not very sure what you want to say....

Answer (score 3):

In your `main()` function,

```
L->head->item=1;
```

`L->head` is uninitialized. By de-referencing, you're invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory to `L->head` before you de-reference that pointer.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it! I have a question though. How do I know when I need to use malloc to allocate memory to a pointer first? For example,there are certain cases where it is not needed like, int *p=&number .

Comment: @LewWeiHao All the cases where the pointer is not initialized to any valid memory address.